# Query logging tool for Firefox

Tags: firefox, logging, search-engine

I am looking for a way to log my own queries I submit to Google in Firefox. Is there a way so I can store them in a log file?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need write an add-on and you can use many tools for solve this.
You can chose:

- HTTP Observers
- Listening to events on tabs
- Load Events
- WebProgressListeners

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Intercepting_Page_Loads

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Listening_to_events_on_all_tabs

To log JS msj (error, warnings, logs) to disk, set the environment variable XRE_CONSOLE_LOG to the path to the filename. i.e. export XRE_CONSOLE_LOG=/path/to/logfile or set XRE_CONSOLE_LOG=C:\path\to\logfile.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/XULRunner/Debugging_XULRunner_applications

Or you can create files

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/NetUtil.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
// get the "data.txt" file in the profile directory
var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["GoogleQuery.txt"]);    

// You can also optionally pass a flags parameter here. It defaults to
// FileUtils.MODE_WRONLY | FileUtils.MODE_CREATE | FileUtils.MODE_TRUNCATE;
var ostream = FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream(file);

var converter = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/intl/scriptableunicodeconverter"].
                createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIScriptableUnicodeConverter);
converter.charset = "UTF-8";
var istream = converter.convertToInputStream(data);

// The last argument (the callback) is optional.
NetUtil.asyncCopy(istream, ostream, function(status) {
  if (!Components.isSuccessCode(status)) {
    // Handle error!
    return;
  }

// Data has been written to the file.
//data is your string of your Google queries
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out all the info. You don't know by any chance if someone has already made an add-on like this? I had a look but couldn't find anything.

Comment: You need clear: "own queries I submit to Google"
You can see the history and take the queries also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an add-on for Firefox or IE to log queries

http://www.lemurproject.org/querylogtoolbar/